# Move an app to the sd card

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard, android-sdk-tools

I have a Z667TV1.0.0B08 Android phone with a 16 gb sd card.
I have tried enabling debug mode and using the command "adb set-install-location 2" and "adb get-install-location" which outputs "2[external]."
How do I move an app to the sd card, or make it the default install location?

Comment: what version is your android?

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with API Level 8, you can allow your application to be installed on the external storage (for example, the device's SD card). you can declare for your application with the android:installLocation manifest attribute. for more details please visit http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html